# Getting the text baseline of a date input element

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a way to get the vertical baseline of the text inside a date input element in order to compare it against the baseline of the caption for the input, to ensure they are level.

So far I have mostly been using getBoundingClientRect() to try to get the basline position, but for the date input this is getting the bottom of the input, rather than the text in the input.

Does anybody know a way to get the pixel position of the baseline of the text inside the date input element?

Comment: please provide screenshots and draw lines of what you mean